# Filter data in Twitter Streaming API

Tags: api, twitter, filter

I'm currently experimenting with the Twitter Streaming API. Everything work's like a charm, but the API sends me ton's of data, which I don't need. Is there a possibility to filter the data the API send me?

I'm using the following stream: https://stream.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/filter.json

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at the filter stream of the api:

> https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/post/statuses/filter

You can enter a set of keywords as a filter to track twitter, according to current  limitations you can track up to 400 keywords.

After retrieving the tweets you have to make a manual filtering again to remove noisy data.

So if you can specify what you are looking by a set of keywords, you will achieve what you want; but there will always be noise in your data because it is almost impossible to define smtg that precisely through simple keyword filtering.

For example lets assume you wanna track all tweets related to a brand named XYZ. For getting tweets about brand `XYZ` you might have a one word keyword set which contains only "XYZ". API will give all the tweets containing `XYZ` to you, but assume that "XYZ" has a meaning in some language and people of speaking that language will tweet about that word and you will receive that too. Also assume there is a city called XYZ and people will send check-in mesasgees. So at that point you need to filter out tweets that are not related to your topic, either by language detection or contextual information retrieval. But the key is to specify your keyword set about the topic you wanna cover.

Cheers.

Comment: Hi, thank's for that, but the problem is that i don't even want to receive the "Noisy" data, as i want to process lot's of tweets in less time :) Maybe it isn't even podsible to get a "short" version of the tweets from the api.

Comment: @LucèBrùlè I edited my answer to clarify whats the noise data.

Comment: @cubbuk : Suppose i specified 3 keywords in the filter. Now when i get data from streaming API, is there a way (other than manually searching on my own) to detect that the tweet corresponds to WHICH of the three  keywords that i specified in the filter ?

Comment: @user1599964 as far as I know, twitter doesn't provide any info about that, you have to figure it out manually yourself.

Comment: @cubbuk : Yes, i figured that out. Can you have a look at this question and let me know your views: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16602483/filtering-of-tweets-received-from-statuses-filter-streaming-api

Comment: is there any tool which can help me for language detection?

Comment: @cubbuk : will the streaming API also include tweets like abXYZcd or XYZmn. Does it give me tweets which contain the filter substring?. For example if I filter for "fast", will it give me tweets like "breakfast"?.

Comment: @KrishnaKalyan I just don't know the current status, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

answer is "**No**" for the question "is there a way (other than manually searching on my own) to detect that the tweet corresponds to WHICH of the three keywords that i specified in the filter ?"  We have to do it manually ..

Answer (score 0):

If it is possible you can [migrate to twitter APIv2](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/migrate/data-formats/standard-v1-1-to-v2), since, by default it only returns [`id` and `text` parameters](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/data-dictionary/introduction), this reduces incoming data dramatically. Then you can add [fields parameter](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/fields) for extra data you want.

Answer (score -1):

Look at [backtype storm project](http://storm-project.net/documentation.html). there are examples to filter api using twitter4j.

Comment: invalid link from expired domain