# How does Twitter extract Terms from its Tweets in the Filter API

Tags: regex, twitter

Twitter provides a [Streaming API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-apis/parameters#track). This API allows you to query based on terms (Strings).

I am having trouble coming up with a method to pull the terms from each Tweet the way they do. The edge cases, seen below, are giving me the most trouble.

Example Tweet:

```
These are a list of Terms from Twitter's filter API www.example.com
```

Extracted terms according to their [testing page](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-apis/keyword-matching).

- these
- are
- list
- of
- terms
- from
- twitter's
- twitter
- s
- filter
- api
- www.example.com
- www
- example
- com
- example.com/

If you look at the example, you will notice a few oddities.

First, if I were to split the Tweet up by white-space, it would include the word `a`. However, that has been excluded. On a quick glance, one might assume they are simply ignoring anything of length(1). Unfortunately, the word `Twitter's` has been split into `twitter's`, `twitter`, and `s` with the term `s` being of length(1).

Secondly, URLs are not completely obvious to me. I do know from the documentation that they also use extra Meta-Data stored in the tweet to do additional matching on URLs. The URL in this example is pretty simple but feel free to play with the [tool](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-apis/keyword-matching) to judge more complex examples.

I am trying to come up with a method to associate each returned Tweet with the Tracking Term(s) that found it. So far, it's looking *close* but the edge cases are turning this job into a nightmare. Preferably, I'd like to have a regular expression for performance's sake -- but without a well defined rule-set, that's pretty difficult to build.

**What is an accurate way to extract terms similar to how Twitter does it?** Code, pseudo-code, regular expressions, or links to existing implementation would be great!

---

- Similar post: [filtering of tweets received from statuses/filter (streaming API)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16602483/filtering-of-tweets-received-from-statuses-filter-streaming-api)

Comment: Somebody voted to close this based on it being "off-topic". Can you please at least add a comment and explain why you believe that and if there are any modifications I can make to fix that? This is a question about understanding an algorithm and defining an implementation, preferably with code samples. I'm not sure how that is off-topic from programming.

Comment: The off topic reason assuming you can't see it is: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it." which seems valid since your actual question is "What is an accurate way to extract terms similar to how Twitter does it? Code, pseudo-code, regular expressions, or links to existing implementation would be great!".

Comment: Ahh okay, thank you. Is there a better place to ask this type of question? SuperUser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly how Twitter builds this list of "Extracted Terms" is in the source code to the [test page you have already linked](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-apis/keyword-matching).

It is far more complex than just a simple regex, some of the steps included in source are:

- Extraction of URLs
- Extraction of Twitter Lists
- Extraction of mentions
- Extraction of Hash tags
- Extraction of Cash tags (e.g. `$APPL`)
- Removal of overlapping entities
- Separation of words by whitespace
- Extraction of successions of alphanumerical characters (optionally prefixed with @ or #)

Refer to the source of the page starting at: `// current version of twitter-text.js`

Comment: Wow! I took a quick peek at "resources" (external JS dependencies) but didn't think to check the page's source itself. I didn't expect them to embed it in the page, directly. You aren't kidding -- it's definitely far more complex than a simpler regex. I appreciate you taking the time to flesh out this answer for me.